# Java regex to strip out XML tags, but not tag contents

Tags: java, xml, regex, string

I have the following Java code:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<.*?>.*?</.*?>|<.*?/>", "");
```

This turns a String like so:

```
How now <fizz>brown</fizz> cow.
```

Into:

```
How now  cow.
```

However, I want it to just strip the `<fizz>` and `</fizz>` tags, or just standalone `</fizz`> tags, and leave the element's content alone. So, a regex that would turn the above into:

```
How now brown cow.
```

Or, using a more complex String, somethng that turns:

```
How <buzz>now <fizz>brown</fizz><yoda/></buzz> cow.
```

Into:

```
How now brown cow.
```

I tried this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<.*?></.*?>|<.*?/>", "");
```

And that doesn't work at all. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: usually if `xml` and `regex` tags show together, you would get a comment, it says....

Comment: Have you tried using an XML parser? I find my life much easier with JDOM for parsing XML.

Comment: I can't go into details without dropping into a huge backstory but thats not possible here (XML Parser). Just looking for a regex solution.

Comment: put an '|' between the first > and <.

Comment: if you really want to use regex, don't mention any xml in your question, and just say "text", :D... you could try `replaceAll("<[^>]*>","")`

Comment: (If you're wondering, "What's wrong with using regex with xml?" [here's the canonical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), although actually both that question and this can fairly be done with regex.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
"How now <fizz>brown</fizz> cow.".replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "")
```

Comment: Very efficient and compact.

Answer (score 7):

You were almost there ;)

Try this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<.*?>", "")
```

Comment: I tested it with Notepad++ and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

While there are other correct answers, none give any explanation.

The reason your regex `<.*?>.*?</.*?>|<.*?/>` doesn't work is because it will select any tags **as well as everything inside them**. You can see that in action on [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%3C.%2a?%3E.%2a?%3C/.%2a?%3E%7C%3C.%2a?/%3E&str=How%20%3Cbuzz%3Enow%20%3Cfizz%3Ebrown%3C/fizz%3E%3Cyoda/%3E%3C/buzz%3E%20cow.).

The reason your second attempt `<.*?></.*?>|<.*?/>` doesn't work is because it will select from the beginning of a tag **up to the first close tag following a tag**. That is kind of a mouthful, but you can understand better what's going on [in this example](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%3C.%2a?%3E%3C/.%2a?%3E%7C%3C.%2a?/%3E&str=How%20%3Cbuzz%3Enow%20%3Cfizz%3Ebrown%3C/fizz%3E%3Cyoda/%3E%3C/buzz%3E%20cow.).

The regex you need is much simpler: `<.*?>`. It simply selects every tag, ignoring if it's open/close. [Visualization](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%3C.%2a?%3E&str=How%20%3Cbuzz%3Enow%20%3Cfizz%3Ebrown%3C/fizz%3E%3Cyoda/%3E%3C/buzz%3E%20cow.).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");
```

Please have a look at the below example for better understanding:

```
public class StringUtils {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(StringUtils.replaceAll("How now <fizz>brown</fizz> cow."));
        System.out.println(StringUtils.replaceAll("How <buzz>now <fizz>brown</fizz><yoda/></buzz> cow."));
    }

    public static String replaceAll(String strInput) {
        return strInput.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
How now brown cow.
How now brown cow.
```

Comment: -1. Angle brackets (`<` and `>`) have no special meaning in regexes, so escaping them is pointless.  In fact, in some flavors (but not Java) `\<` and `\>` are used to match word boundaries, so this "solution" would make things worse.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't  elegant, but it is easy to follow. The below code removes the start and end XML  tags if they are present in a line together

`<url>"www.xml.com"<\url> , <body>"This is xml"<\body>`

Regex :

```
to_replace='<\w*>|<\/\w*>',value=""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse XML log file so you can do with regex {java}, `<[^<]+<`.so you get `<name>DEV</name>`. Output like name>DEV. You have to just play with REGEX.